# Does UWP Composition Api support color replacement?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-composition-api, xaml-composition

I've been trying to look for an examples which related to Color Replacement, here's an example using the Photoshop which can take, for example, a Blue shade and replace it with a Red shade:

**BEFORE:**
[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

Is this possible using the Composition Effects in the latest version of Composition Api?

I've seen examples related to Hue Rotations and Temperature and Tint:

https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/uwp-composition-effects-hue-rotation/

https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/uwp-composition-effects-temperature-and-tint/

But I'm wondering if the api is capable of using Effects to switch a color range in an image ??

Comment: Here's the ColorMatrixEffect mentioned by Johhny for anyone who wants to further look into such a feature:

http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_ColorMatrixEffect.htm


I also did stumble on a blog which uses Effects to alter the Tint/Temperature of an image. It not's exactly what I wanted but it's close and I can use it.

http://blog.robmikh.com/uwp/composition/2016/04/21/images-and-effects.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution you may like. The sample looks like this:

[image]

To achieve this I used 3 effects in a chain: `PixelShaderEffect`, `GaussianBlurEffect` and `BlendEffect` from **Win2d** API.

XAML has `CanvasAnimatedControl` to draw the result plus some helpers like source (the color we want to replace) and replace color pickers and threshold slider.

```
<Grid>
    <xaml:CanvasAnimatedControl x:Name="AnimatedControl"
                            CreateResources="AnimatedControl_OnCreateResources"
                            Draw="AnimatedControl_OnDraw"/>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock Text="Source Color" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"/>

        <ColorSpectrum Width="256" Height="256" ColorChanged="ColorSpectrum_OnColorChanged"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock Text="Replace Color" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"/>

        <ColorSpectrum Width="256" Height="256" ColorChanged="ColorSpectrum_OnColorChanged1"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Slider Width="512" ValueChanged="RangeBase_OnValueChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private PixelShaderEffect _textureShader;
    private GaussianBlurEffect _blur;
    private BlendEffect _blend;

    private void AnimatedControl_OnCreateResources(CanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
    {
        args.TrackAsyncAction(CreateResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
    }

    private async Task CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasAnimatedControl sender)
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Shaders/TextureTest.bin"));
        var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

        var sourceImage = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.jpg"));

        _textureShader = new PixelShaderEffect(buffer.ToArray())
        {
            Source1 = sourceImage
        };

        _blur = new GaussianBlurEffect
        {
            BlurAmount = 4,
            Source = _textureShader
        };

        _blend = new BlendEffect
        {
            Foreground = _blur,
            Background = sourceImage,
            Mode = BlendEffectMode.Color
        };
    }

    private void AnimatedControl_OnDraw(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(_blend);
    }

    private void RangeBase_OnValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _textureShader.Properties["threshold"] = (float)e.NewValue / 100;
    }

    private void ColorSpectrum_OnColorChanged(ColorSpectrum sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _textureShader.Properties["sourceColor"] = new Vector3((float)args.NewColor.R / 255, (float)args.NewColor.G / 255, (float)args.NewColor.B / 255);
    }

    private void ColorSpectrum_OnColorChanged1(ColorSpectrum sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _textureShader.Properties["replaceColor"] = new Vector3((float)args.NewColor.R / 255, (float)args.NewColor.G / 255, (float)args.NewColor.B / 255);
    }
```

And the most exciting thing is a pixel shader:

```
#define D2D_INPUT_COUNT 1
#define D2D_INPUT0_SIMPLE

#include "d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli"

float3 sourceColor;
float3 replaceColor;
float threshold;

D2D_PS_ENTRY(main)
{
    float3 color = D2DGetInput(0).rgb;

    if (abs(color.r - sourceColor.r) < threshold && abs(color.g - sourceColor.g) < threshold && abs(color.b - sourceColor.b) < threshold) 
    {
        float3 newColor = color - sourceColor + replaceColor;
        return float4(newColor.r, newColor.g, newColor.b, 1);
    }
    else 
    {
        return float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

To compile it you should take a tour here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/ExampleGallery/Shared/Shaders

There's cmd file that compiles your hlsl shaders. If you need some help - comment it. Have fun!

Comment: Wow!! That is amazing!!!  Thanks for the detailed explanation! I would've never figured this out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is a blur effect involved if there is no blurring in the output.

Comment: Without blur the output would be too pixelated. You may set `BlurAmount = 0` to observe the difference.

Comment: Chopper, quick question, since I've never worked with Win2D. Where is the link between the code and the HSLS shader? I don't see it referenced in the code-behind.

Comment: When you compile hlsl shader you receive a binary file in my case it's `TextureTest.bin` (my shader is called TextureTest.hlsl). Don't forget to include this file in your project and select build action as `Content` in it's properties.

Comment: Hi again Jet, the shader is working really well, and I managed to get the image to stretch correctly. If I want to take this a step further, for example, allow 2 or 3 colors to be replaced simultaneously, I'm assuming I would have to set a Source2 and Source3 for the PixelShader and modify the hlsl file to have more inputs? Also, from looking at the hlsl code, I would also add sourceColor2, replacecolor2, etc...

Comment: Yes, Win2d PixelShaderEffect supports up to 8 texture inputs and a lot of propeties. You may modify shader as you wish just follow the same algorithm

Comment: Followed the pattern, got stuck on the "return" value. I made an issue but no one figured it out. I figured you can gain more points if you know the answer :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598891/support-more-than-one-color-input-in-my-pixel-shader-uwp-win2d